# Facebook Messaging API Access Token based on Group's Page?

Tags: facebook, access-token, messaging

I want to use the Facebook Messaging API to send messages to our classmates regarding a reunion.

When setting up the Access Token, it is asking me to connect a page.

I would like it to be attached to our classes Group page, but I don't see it listed as a Page that can be used.

[image: Access Token Screen]

[image: Page Selection Screen]

Comment: Pages and groups are different things. You can not create an access token "for" a group, and groups are not part of what the messaging API covers either - that's for communication between a user, and a page.

Comment: Thank you for the info @CBroe.  I created a Page under my personal account and was able to create an access token for that.  If you want to post that as the answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like it to be attached to our classes Group page, but I don't see it listed as a Page that can be used.

Pages and groups are different things. You can not create an access token "for" a group, and groups are not part of what the messaging API covers either - that's for communication between a user, and a page.

Comment: Do users need to like a page or subscribe in some way, in order to message them through the API?  I have a rather robust Google Sheets project where I've collected up to date information for our classmates. I'm using it to keep track of RSVPs and headcounts for our upcoming reunion.  I need a way to DM our classmates personalized messages. I figured it would be rather straightforward if the users were already a member of the group and the access token was based on the same.

Comment: You can not just start sending messages to users, they need to opt-in to that in some form. And you can not reply just whenever you like either, they have a 24 hour "window" in which you can reply to a user's message, and restrictions on how often you can message them before requiring a user response again ... You will really have to go and read up on this in the documentation in more detail.

Comment: _"I'm using it to keep track of RSVPs and headcounts for our upcoming reunion"_ - if you had just added an event on Facebook and invited your group members, then you could've had that kind of functionality already built-in, without any extra work ...

Comment: I see. That's kind-of why I was hoping to use the Group's page, since everyone is already a member. I guess I'll have to resort to some kind of client-side automation..